# вывест на страницу одни значения, без ключа

Tags: php

использую phpmorphy
такой код:

```
$word = 'УРЮПИНСК';


$city = var_dump($morphy->castFormByGramInfo($word, null, array('ЕД', 'ПР'), true));
echo $city;
```

необходимо вывести название города в предложном падеже.

выложу весь код, может здесь где ошибся:

```
<?php
    // Подключите файл common.php. phpmorphy-0.3.2 - для версии 0.3.2,
    // если используется иная версия исправьте код.
    require_once( 'phpmorphy-0.3.7/src/common.php');

    // Укажите путь к каталогу со словарями
    $dir = 'phpmorphy-0.3.7/dicts';

    // Укажите, для какого языка будем использовать словарь.
    // Язык указывается как ISO3166 код страны и ISO639 код языка, 
    // разделенные символом подчеркивания (ru_RU, uk_UA, en_EN, de_DE и т.п.)

    $lang = 'ru_RU';

    // Укажите опции
    // Список поддерживаемых опций см. ниже
    $opts = array(
        'storage' => PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_FILE,
    );

    // создаем экземпляр класса phpMorphy
    // обратите внимание: все функции phpMorphy являются throwable т.е. 
    // могут возбуждать исключения типа phpMorphy_Exception (конструктор тоже)
    try {
        $morphy = new phpMorphy($dir, $lang, $opts);
    } catch(phpMorphy_Exception $e) {
        die('Error occured while creating phpMorphy instance: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    // далее под $morphy мы подразумеваем экземпляр класса phpMorphy
    $word = 'УРЮПИНСК';
    $city = var_dump($morphy->castFormByGramInfo($word, null, array('ЕД', 'ПР'), true));
    echo $city;
?>
```

Comment: в переменной $city хранится массив, чтобы получить значение, нужно указать ключ `$city = $morphy->castFormByGramInfo($word, null, array('ЕД', 'ПР'), true)[0];`

Comment: ругается, выдает синтаксическую ошибку

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу, что хранится в переменной $city

Comment: массив со склонениями слова, с помощью phpmorphy хочу изменить падеж города, который получаю в другом скрипте, установил по инструкции, дошёл до шага с изменением падежа, и застрял, не пойму как привести к правильному виду

Comment: Это я понял. Покажите как выглядит массив

Comment: Сейчас нет возможности, что -то вроде того: array{[0]: string 'Урюпинске'}

Comment: тогда я все правильно вам написал. `$city = $morphy->castFormByGramInfo($word, null, array('ЕД', 'ПР'), true)[0]`

Comment: пишет ошибку: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in Z:\hom.... вот так выглядит $city на странице,если оставить var_dump: array(1) { [0]=> string(18) "УРЮПИНСКЕ" }

Comment: `$city = $morphy->castFormByGramInfo($word, null, array('ЕД', 'ПР'), true); echo $city[0];`, если так

Comment: Сработало!!!! Спасибо)))